# Reference a kind of that without using parameterized types in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class that needs to maintain or know about (has-a) reference to three kinds of other classes. What is the best way to provide such a reference?

```
class Hello<T extends IsLetter> {
    private T refOtherClass;
}
// getter and setter for refOtherClass here

interface IsLetter {}

class A implements IsLetter {
    private String a = "A data";
}
class B implements IsLetter {
    private String b = "B data";
}
```

now is there a way to do this without using parameterized types?
Since if Im using parameterized types, any class that uses Hello will need to provide it when creating it (which is fine) but also when using Hello, i cant just say

```
Hello hi = new Hello(); 
// set the refOtherClass ...
hi.getRefOtherClass(); // and here use the refOtherClass like it was of type A
or B, when using hi I need to provide, again, the type that was put in hi.
```

Hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course use a cast:

```
A a = (A) hi.getRefOtherClass();
```

What generics do here is move the verification of this cast to an earlier stage - compile time. If you don't use generics, and if you try to cast to the wrong type, you'll get the error at runtime.

This is in case you need to work with a concrete type. If the interface `IsLetter` (better call it just `Letter`) has all the methods, just make the method return `Letter` and work with the interface.

You can get the exact class of an object by calling `object.getClass()`, or perhaps use an if-clause like `if (a instanceof A)`

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to. How do I know that in fact getRefOtherClass is of type A and not B ? That is what Im asking. How to know what a reference is pointing to, and cast it to that if necessary, maybe I should use instanceof?

Comment: @AntonioP If you don't know it at compile time, what do you want to do with it at runtime?

Comment: I think we are confused because you are not really asking the right questions.

Comment: I see, that is a good question Bozho. I will think about it some more. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Your poor explanation probably didn't get you any anwers. But here is a try of what i think you are asking.

So first you need to do this:

```
Hello<A> hi = new Hello<A>();
```

Because you are using generics in Java.

Now you can do

```
A a = hi.getRefOtherClass();
//or
IsLetter a = hi.getRefOtherClass();
```

Finally, you should probaby put a method on you interface like so:

```
interface IsLetter{ String getValue();}
```

Which of course then you can do `a.getValue();` And because of the beauty of OO, you can return "B VALUE" from B or "A Value" from A.

Comment: he appears to know that, and is asking how to do it without the generics

Comment: Ah i didn't see that part. Now why would you ever do that :)

Comment: Because A and B are not really similar, except that Hello can reference them both. So I cant add getValue(), getOtherblabla() in interface, since them both (or more) might not even provide such Value and Otherblabla.

Comment: You have lost me there. Maybe its because you think you have to implement an interface to use generics. Which is not true. You could just do class Hello<T>{}. Try asking your question again because you should want to try to use generics. They are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you want to do this without generics - this is exactly the sort of situation generics make clearer:

```
class Hello<T extends IsLetter> { 
   public T getRefOtherClass(){ ... }
 }

class A implements IsLetter { ... }

class B implements IsLetter { ... }

Hello hi = new Hello<A>();
A a = hi.getRefOtherClass();
```

You can only get rid of the parameterization by casting the output of the get method, which is messier, or by subclassing the Hello so that the parameterization is "encapsulated" in your subclassing (which might make sense in some cases, although not in a simple example like this ) e.g.

```
 class HelloA extends Hello<A> {...
  A a = new HelloA.get()
```

But again, you're not getting rid of the generics, you're just shifting them around.